# Why are some Windows and Chrome fonts thin and hard to read after re-installation of Windows 10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

I had to re-install Windows 10 on my Dell laptop.
But now sometimes black font on white background is really thin and hard to see.

Comment: Run Clear Type, restart, and see if that helps

Comment: is it everywhere or only in the browser?

Comment: John, Clear Type did not help.  d0rf47, yes, but only sometimes, and if background is white.  For example, this serupuser question on Chrome is okay, easy to read.  But Beyond Compare window with white background has very thin black foreground text.